# Node.js, python for API

Tags: python, node.js, rest, api, backend

I want to build REST API which will communicate with MYSQL DB The application will have some heavy processing after I fetch data from DB and return. Node.js being single threaded might have some issues i fell.

I want to know if I should go with node.js or python is there any other technology I should be using ?

Comment: Voting to close as opinion based. For example, Ruby, PHP, Golang, Java would all work fine, depending on your experience level

Comment: @cricket_007 People are helping me in comments section. Freeware which does not cause license issues for me also needs to be kept in mind. Just having experience is not good enough in technologies which will cause legal issues.. That is why I mentioned Python vs node.js.

Answer (score 1):

With my exp, python work with MySQL better than NodeJS in multi thread. But i think you should try some other solution if it's really heavy process, like using Spark for data processing.

Comment: you could use django rest framework https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: As long as my application does not stop responding (like i know in node.js it will) I am ok to use python. Thanks. I will explore Spark as well. thanks for suggestion.